# Getting list and dict values - Django

Tags: python, django

I have a problem. I am new to django and trying to figure out how can I get specific values out of a list and a dict from views.py. I have the following dict output:

```
{'meta_title': u'Alaska State Fair Events', 'varos_id': 2886429L, 'longitude': -149.13053600000001, 'name': u'Palmer', 'thumbnail_id': 8406L, 'image': u'photologue/photos/2c18fe09-275b-4770-aab6-230cff72b2ee.jpg', 'orszag_id': u'US', 'helyszin': u'Alaska State Fair, 2075 Glenn Highway Palmer, AK 99645, United States ', 'slug': u'alaska-state-fair-palmer-ak', 'latitude': 61.580159999999999, 'allam_id': u'AK', 'nev': u'Alaska State Fair, Palmer, AK', 'id': 2886429L}
```

What I want to do is quite simple. I want to address the variables like `image=szorakozohelyquery('image')` which would result in 
`image=photologue/photos/2c18fe09-275b-4770-aab6-230cff72b2ee.jpg`

Is there an easy way to do this? Also what is the easiest way to do this from a list?

Comment: Read the [python documentation for dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: When you say dict output, what do you mean? Is that a dict from a django request or just a normal dict?

Comment: can you post  the list example do you want

Answer (score 3):

d.get('image','default value') willprevent you from key error if key is not there in dictionary d

```
>>> d ={'image':'a.jpg'}
>>> d.get('image','not found')
'a.jpg'
>>> d={}
>>> d.get('image','not found')
'not found'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

`d['image']` will get you the value for key: `'image'`, from the dict: `d`.

... which will be: `u'photologue/photos/2c18fe09-275b-4770-aab6-230cff72b2ee.jpg'`.

> "Also what is the easiest way to do this from a list?"

A list is a different data structure:

```
>>> my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> print my_list[0]
a
```

see: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html for more info on lists and dicts.